# Avoid Downstream projects to build if one of the up stream projects fails

Tags: jenkins

We have one CI set up with following configuration

Build 1-> MT1

Build 2 -> MT2

Both Build 1 and Build 2 are parallel and so are MT1 and MT2; MT1 will get triggered only if Build 1 succeeds;

The actual requirment we have is there is one post-processing  (PP1) job after MT1 and MT2 which gets triggered after completion of MT1 and MT2; and we dont want this Post Processing PP1 to get triggered if Build 1 or Build 2 fails;

Any help how we can achieve this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Build Flow Plug in

Using this plug in, you can create your own build sequence. It is having many options for customizing the build flow.

Please see this link for examples and implementation.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

Comment: Hi Manu,

Thanks for the info; Build Flow Plug in is good but this will make me to rework on complete CI set up we have;

I am looking for some plugin with minimal changes; I have used *Block build when upstream project is building* option in Jenkins configuration but the issue with this configuration is post processing job is never triggered as keeps waiting for upstream projects to complete; as we do repetitive build;

Any other suggestion will be appreciated.